# How to track input from the user during a method. Scanner Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I'm making a text adventure game in java and I have this method that prints text, letter by letter to give the impression that the text are being written.

Now I'm trying to, if the player **press enter** while the text are being written, then it prints all the left text...
SomeThing like:

```java
 if(...) speed=0;     //Because if the speed is 0 prints the text normaly
```

I had tried to use some Scanner methods like hasNextLine() and nextLine() but that does not worked for me xD. If someone knows how to do it, please helppp :D.

```
private static void printString(String text, int speed) {
    
    int counter=0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
             
        char character = text.charAt(i);
        counter++;
        
        System.out.printf("%c", character); 
                      
        //goes to next line if the text is too long
        if(Character.compare('\n',character)==0) counter=0;
        if(counter>=60 && text.length()-i>50 && Character.compare(' ',character)==0) {
            counter=0; System.out.println("");
        }
        
        coolDown(speed); //Cooldown between letters

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we can't tell you what you did wrong, when you don't post your attempt with Scanner.

Comment: I tried a lot of things... like   if(in.hasNextLine()) but that just do it every time  or     if(in.nextLine().equals("")) but that makes it wait for input :/

Comment: You can check [Java input without pausing](//stackoverflow.com/q/7504641), it provides a possible solution